# Div show auto generated inline style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have taken a 'div' element and at run time the 'div' shows some auto generated inline style. How i should stop such inline style?

```
<div class="Radius_Div_Square" id="UserNoteExpand" 
     style="overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto; height:4px;" sizcache="3" sizset="339;">
```

In code sample you can see `height:4px;` that i have to stop.

Comment: Where are you getting this div from?

Answer (score 1):

That inline styling must be added by some other library or framework.

You must find out what is causing that.

Or you can overwrite the height attribute with another (external) stylesheet like

```
#UserNoteExpand {
    height: 100px !important;
}
```

However, the latter is quite dirty...

Comment: yea maybe dirty but functional...imo multiple css / js libs together (like bootstrap and custom scripts) are a way of dirty anyway...

Comment: I tried but not working.My scenario is i am calling user control under model popup extender and that popup is on other user control on main aspx page.

Comment: Please add more relevant example code / create a reproducing jsfiddle if possible.